# alter function of package within another function in R

Tags: r

I am creating my own function that manipulates data by parameters input by the user,and outputting the desired image using RCircos. The issue i'm having is that the color selection of the RCircos package doesn't directly fit my need. I've found the function within the package and have altered it within my own .R source file to fit my color selection needs. Is there a straightforward way to feed the "corrected" function into RCircos within my own function?

Comment: Create your own package.

Comment: I can assure you that it works if used properly. `RCircos` is not an object from that package, so I have no idea what you're attempting to do.